# VBA: Get a ComboBox to display unique values to choose from filter sheet data - to then run a specific search through filtered data

Tags: excel, vba, object, filter, combobox

Hello and thank you for clicking and spending your time. I am not proud to just ask for help, but due to a deadline for this project I am running out of time to properly understand and solve it myself.

I have a macro that is running a code for a string search to display lots of different necessary data from a sheet called (Tabelle1). But I need to be able to filter that sheet data first, based on a "Shipment Number" in a column ("L"), to only get the corresponding column's (total 27, from "A" to "AA") data for each shipment that I have to then run the search process on.

It would be ideal (if even possible) that when the shipment is chosen (clicked from the drop-down list) that the search/input bar (userinput.KeyUp) is selected automatically, so that the search string can be entered right into it.

I figured that a ComboBox might do the job. To display in its drop-down menu all unique shipment numbers (ideally only once). I suspect it won't be done by just adding a ComboBox and writing it's function separately (but I can't even get that going), I will need to connect it to the already existing search code, that didn't have a ComboBox/filter function included when written.

Here is a condensed example of my data sheet:

[Sheet "Tabelle1"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvkTh.png)

Exmaple of the object I created:

[Screenshot of Input Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXLAD.png)

Here is the whole code, with my lousy attempt of the ComboBox integration:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

Dim lastr As Integer
    lastr = Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tabelle1").Range("A:AA" & lastr).AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:=Range("L1").Value, Operator:=xlFilterValues
    
End Sub

Private Sub Frame1_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub Frame2_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub Label1_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub Label13_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub Label2_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub lastbin_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub Label9_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub limiter_a_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub limiter_b_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub locationfound_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub partfound_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub partnotein_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub partspecialin_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub quickbin2_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub lineqtydetail_Change()

End Sub

Private Sub partqtyinfound_Change()

End Sub

Private Sub TestCountMultiple()

End Sub

Public Sub UserForm_Initialize()

limiter_a = "^#01^"
limiter_b = "^#02^"

End Sub

Private Sub suchbutton_Click()

Dim fullstring, searchstring As String
Dim partfound, locationfound, partqtyinfound As String
Dim partnotein, partspecialin, lastbin As String
Dim columnpart, columnlocation, lineqtydetail As String
Dim quickbin2 As String
Dim ergebnis As String
Dim j As Long
Dim lenght_a, lenght_b As Long
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tabelle1")

columnpart = "M"
columnlocation = "C"
quickbin2 = "D"
partqtyinfound = "N"
partnotein = "P"
partspecialin = "Q"
lastbin = "B"
lineqtydetail = "O"

lenght_a = Len(limiter_a)
lenght_b = Len(limiter_b)

fullstring = SucheTeilenummer.userinput.Value

openPos = InStr(fullstring, limiter_a)
closePos = InStr(fullstring, limiter_b)

If openPos > "0" And closePos > "0" Then
    searchstring = Mid(fullstring, openPos + lenght_a, closePos - openPos - lenght_b)
Else
    ergebnis = "Keine Limiter gefunden"
End If

If ergebnis = "Keine Limiter gefunden" Then
    SucheTeilenummer.partfound = ergebnis
    SucheTeilenummer.locationfound = ""
    SucheTeilenummer.partqtyinfound = ""
    Suche.Teilenummer.partnotein = ""
    Suche.Teilenummer.partspecialin = ""
    Suche.Teilenummer.lastbin = ""
    Suche.Teilenummer.lineqtydetail = ""
    Suche.Teilenummer.quickbin2 = ""
Else
    letzteZeileTeilenummer = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, columnpart).End(xlUp).Row
    For j = letzteZeileTeilenummer To 2 Step -1
        
        If Range(columnpart & j).Value = searchstring Then
            booFOUND = True
            
            SucheTeilenummer.partfound = ws.Range(columnpart & j).Value
            SucheTeilenummer.locationfound = ws.Range(columnlocation & j).Value
            SucheTeilenummer.partqtyinfound = ws.Range(partqtyinfound & j).Value
            SucheTeilenummer.partnotein = ws.Range(partnotein & j).Value
            SucheTeilenummer.partspecialin = ws.Range(partspecialin & j).Value
            SucheTeilenummer.lastbin = ws.Range(lastbin & j).Value
            SucheTeilenummer.lineqtydetail = ws.Range(lineqtydetail & j).Value & Chr(vbKeySpace) & "PCS" & " - " & ws.Range(columnpart & j).Value & vbCrLf & ws.Range(partnotein & j).Value & vbCrLf & "##################" & vbCrLf & SucheTeilenummer.lineqtydetail
            SucheTeilenummer.quickbin2 = ws.Range(quickbin2 & j).Value
            
            ergebnis = "Wert gefunden"
        Else
            ergebnis = "Wert nicht gefunden"
        End If
        
    Next j
        
        If booFOUND Then
            ergebnis = "Wert gefunden"
        Else
            ergebnis = "Wert nicht gefunden"
        End If

End If
        
        If ergebnis = "Wert nicht gefunden" Then
            SucheTeilenummer.partfound = searchstring
            SucheTeilenummer.locationfound = ""
            SucheTeilenummer.partqtyinfound = ""
            SucheTeilenummer.partnotein = ""
            SucheTeilenummer.partspecialin = ""
            SucheTeilenummer.lastbin = ""
            SucheTeilenummer.lineqtydetail = ""
            SucheTeilenummer.quickbin2 = ""
        End If

SucheTeilenummer.userinput.Value = ""
fullstring = ""
ergebnis = ""
SucheTeilenummer.userinput.SetFocus

End Sub

Private Sub userinput_KeyUp(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)

If KeyCode = vbKeyReturn Then 'wenn die Taste vbKeyReturn ist was für 13 steht dann soll die Suche gestartet werden
    Call suchbutton_Click
    KeyCode = 0 'hier wird der Key für die nächste Suche resettet
End If

End Sub

Private Sub userinput_change()
If InStr(SucheTeilenummer.userinput.Value, limiter_b) Then 'wenn in dem Einfgabefeld irgendwo der limiter_b auftaucht, dann soll die Suche gestartet werden
    Call suchbutton_Click
End If

End Sub
```

Kind regards,
Erol.

What did you try and what were you expecting?
Tried to google a similar problem and apply it to my code. Wasn't able to get it to run. Sorry, thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with _"to only get the corresponding column's (total 27, from "A" to "AA") data for each shipment that I have to then run the search process on."_, is that the Values being given to `SucheTeilenummer` or do columns need to be hidden on your sheet? Also, why do you have `Suche.Teilenummer` in your second If-clause?

Comment: Hi. I can't give you a clear explanation on the second if-clause, since I didn't write the code. But what that does is search the entire sheet based on what is entered into the Input Bar (see second attached image, in yellow). So yes, I suppose what I need the ComboBox Filter to do is hide all information/values that relate to other shipments, except the one that was chosen from the drop down menu in the combobox. I hope that makes more sense.

Comment: Are the `letzteZeileTeilenummer` (I'm not fluent enough to fully translate this) unique? Or is that why the searching is going from bottom to top (letzte means last afaik hence the question)?

Comment: Yes, that stands for last row (teilenummer = item number). The search does goes from bottom to top. I'm not sure why.

Comment: That doesn't tell me if they're unique, if all M-values are unique, you don't need to filter to find the values you're looking for. If they're unique per shipping number, then the filter comes in handy.

Comment: The values (shipping numbers) are all unique, but they are listed multiple times in column "L". There may be 1000+ lines. Shipment "10199324" exists only once, but the list does show 300 lines because that shipment contains 300 line items. But it's a unique value, yes.

Comment: If I recall correctly, you have the shipment numbers in the L-column and the item numbers in the M-column. Are the item numbers *all* unique or are they only unique per shipping number?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do the following now and I, at the very least, was able to get the ComboBox to search the values within the column I want to filter. But it does nothing more but show me the values in the box once I start typing in the first numbers:

[Drop Down works but...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p23Wy.png)

But I'm trying to populate each value once in the drop down field (though the column itself has it listed in multiple cells due to the nature of the data). And once I choose a shipment number, I would need the data to filter all the information on the sheet with all other corresponding values to that specific shipping number in column "L" (hide everything that doesn't belong to that shipment, but to a differnt one).

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

    FilterCbo1 (UCase(ComboBox1.Value))
    ComboBox1.DropDown
    
End Sub

Public Sub FilterCbo1(strFilter As String)

Dim lastrow As Long
    lastrow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tabelle1").Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For Each strchoice In Range(Cells(2, 12), Cells(lastrow, 12))
            If InStr(1, strchoice, strFilter) <> 0 Then
                SucheTeilenummer.ComboBox1.AddItem strchoice
            End If
        Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can populate your combobox with unique values of your L-column:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Dim lRow As Long
    ShowAll
    lRow = Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tabelle1").Range("A1:AA" & lRow).AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:=ComboBox1.Value, Operator:=xlFilterValues
    Me.userinput.SetFocus 'sets focus to your textbox
    Dim arr, rng As Range
    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tabelle1").Range("A1:AA" & lRow).Offset(1)
    arr = rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value 'could use something like this instead of looping through your cells
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim lRow As Long, i As Long, arr
    ShowAll
    lRow = Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    arr = Range("L2:L" & lRow).Value 'all L-values
    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
            If Not .Exists(arr(i, 1)) Then
                .Add arr(i, 1), Nothing 'keeps only the unique shipping numbers
            End If
        Next i
        ComboBox1.List = .Keys 'gives the combobox those unique numbers all at once
    End With
    limiter_a = "^#01^"
    limiter_b = "^#02^"
End Sub

Private Sub ShowAll()
    On Error Resume Next
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabelle1")
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .ShowAllData
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

And here's how your other code could look like when trimming the unnecessary code:

```
Private Sub suchbutton_Click()

    Dim fullstring As String, searchstring As String
    Dim partfound As String, locationfound As String, partqtyinfound As String
    Dim partnotein As String, partspecialin As String, lastbin As String
    Dim columnpart As String, columnlocation As String, lineqtydetail As String
    Dim quickbin2 As String
    Dim ergebnis As String
    Dim j As Long
    Dim lenght_a As Long, lenght_b As Long
    'Common mistake to not declare your variables for each, i.e. fullString in your code was a Variant, not a string variable
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tabelle1")
    
    columnpart = "M"
    columnlocation = "C"
    quickbin2 = "D"
    partqtyinfound = "N"
    partnotein = "P"
    partspecialin = "Q"
    lastbin = "B"
    lineqtydetail = "O"
    
    lenght_a = Len(limiter_a)
    lenght_b = Len(limiter_b)
    
    fullstring = SucheTeilenummer.userinput.Value
    
    openPos = InStr(fullstring, limiter_a)
    closePos = InStr(fullstring, limiter_b)
    
    If openPos > "0" And closePos > "0" Then
        searchstring = Mid(fullstring, openPos + lenght_a, closePos - openPos - lenght_b)
        letzteZeileTeilenummer = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, columnpart).End(xlUp).Row
        For j = letzteZeileTeilenummer To 2 Step -1
            If Range(columnpart & j).Value = searchstring Then
                booFound = True
                
                SucheTeilenummer.partfound = ws.Range(columnpart & j).Value
                SucheTeilenummer.locationfound = ws.Range(columnlocation & j).Value
                SucheTeilenummer.partqtyinfound = ws.Range(partqtyinfound & j).Value
                SucheTeilenummer.partnotein = ws.Range(partnotein & j).Value
                SucheTeilenummer.partspecialin = ws.Range(partspecialin & j).Value
                SucheTeilenummer.lastbin = ws.Range(lastbin & j).Value
                SucheTeilenummer.lineqtydetail = ws.Range(lineqtydetail & j).Value & Chr(vbKeySpace) & "PCS" & " - " & ws.Range(columnpart & j).Value & vbCrLf & ws.Range(partnotein & j).Value & vbCrLf & "##################" & vbCrLf & SucheTeilenummer.lineqtydetail
                SucheTeilenummer.quickbin2 = ws.Range(quickbin2 & j).Value
                Exit For 'no need to keep searching
            End If
        Next j
    Else
        searchstring = "Keine Limiter gefunden"
    End If
        
    If Not booFound Then
        SucheTeilenummer.partfound = searchstring
        emptySucheForm
    End If

    SucheTeilenummer.userinput.Value = ""
    fullstring = ""
    ergebnis = ""
    SucheTeilenummer.userinput.SetFocus

End Sub

Private Sub emptySucheForm()
    SucheTeilenummer.locationfound = ""
    SucheTeilenummer.partqtyinfound = ""
    SucheTeilenummer.partnotein = ""
    SucheTeilenummer.partspecialin = ""
    SucheTeilenummer.lastbin = ""
    SucheTeilenummer.lineqtydetail = ""
    SucheTeilenummer.quickbin2 = ""
End Sub

Private Sub userinput_KeyUp(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)

If KeyCode = vbKeyReturn Then 'wenn die Taste vbKeyReturn ist was für 13 steht dann soll die Suche gestartet werden
    Call suchbutton_Click
    KeyCode = 0 'hier wird der Key für die nächste Suche resettet
End If

End Sub

Private Sub userinput_change()
If InStr(SucheTeilenummer.userinput.Value, limiter_b) Then 'wenn in dem Einfgabefeld irgendwo der limiter_b auftaucht, dann soll die Suche gestartet werden
    Call suchbutton_Click
End If

End Sub
```

This could be improved if I'd know more about the uniqueness of the M-column's item numbers. I left most of your code as is because if they're not unique and the point was to get the last one, I didn't want to break that logic (for now). If they are, a  use of `Application.Match` comes to mind to get the remaining values in order.

Comment: Thank you for your help and effort. I will try this out as soon as I'm back in the office, but I still wanted to answer now to thank you since I really appreciate it.